# При переходе с MyISAM на InnoDB стало отрицательное количество строк

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb, myisam

Возникла необходимость перейти с `MyISAM` на `InnoDB`. Начал переводить таблицы в `PhpMyAdmin`, все перевелись хорошо, кроме одной. В ней было `448260` записей, сейчас там показывает `-456,201`, это значение кликабельное, если на него нажать, то показывает снова `448260`, если войти в таблицу, то пишет `Отображение строк 0 - 24 (456201 всего, Запрос занял 0.0003 сек.)`. Откуда появилось еще 10000 строк?

Answer (score 2):

Phpmyadmin при больших объемах показывает приблизительное количество строк. Это только для innodb, потому что в этом движке точное количество строк, в отличие от myisam, не хранится.